# Neo4J: test from php cmd line works but web doesn't?

Tags: php, neo4j

Using the following bits:

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client('localhost', 7474);
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
?>
```

If I run this as `php test.php` I get the expected output.

If I run this via `http://server/test.php` I get connection errors.

```
[24-Jun-2014 05:49:52] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' 
  with message 'Can't open connection to http://localhost:7474/db/data/' in 
  /var/www/html/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Transport/Curl.php:91
```

Clearly I've monkeyed up something with either my PHP config or the installation of this library. Suggestions on where to look?

Installed per [these](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) instructions.

Running on CentOS 6.4 (x64), PHP 5.3.3

NOTE: I've made successful connections from *other machines* back to this server so I know the neo4j server is working. It just doesn't seem to want to let me connect locally when called via browser.

Comment: do you run neo4j on the same instance as the php script?

Comment: neo4j runs as a separate java app. php runs either as a stand alone app (works) or as a browser process (doesn't work)

Comment: do you see any output from localhost:7474 when visiting directly? you should see the webadmin of neo4j

Comment: I'm not able to get a browser window as 'localhost' on that machine but the Neo control panel does appear when opened from another machine.

Comment: at least that means there is no problem with the `php` itself, but likely something with firewall or neo4j `server setting` http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html . no other solution comes to my mind

Comment: Does your web server (where PHP is running) run on the same machine as your Neo4j database server? Are you running the PHP from the command line on the same machine that runs your web server?

Comment: yes: cmd line machine = web server = neo4j server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, it was caused by SeLinux

Try disabling it by:

```
 echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

then recheck connection. 
If solved configure SeLinux permissions.
In my case httpd_can_network_connect should be on

```
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
 echo 1 >/selinux/enforce
```

Helpful manual:
http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans